# How should I use css in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to reactJS with ES6 and have read a lot about CSS and the problem they are trying to solve is the global `style.css` and instead use

styles/index.js

```
var styles = {
  transparentBg: {
    background: 'transparent'
  }
};
```

Many argue that you should go back and write CSS (I do not know what reacts name is for CSS, the code above) in each class instead of a separate file if you do not have hundreds of CSS classes. This feels weird. Is it true?

Many CSS frameworks, as popular Bootstrap is still in "old" CSS. Does it matter? Know that the application still works but there must be some reason that react chosen to do it this way. Can I do something about it?

What is the best practice when using CSS and CSS frameworks with ReactJS?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 19):

This is subjective, but in my opinion, it's more practical to use traditional CSS via [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and [PostCSS](https://github.com/postcss/postcss).

For example, you may have a CSS file like this:

```
.btn {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.icon {
  background: url(...);
}
```

Which is used a React component via [`css-loader?modules=true`](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import s from './Button.css';

function Button() {
  return (
    <button className={s.btn}><i className={s.icon} />Click Me</button>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

With the magic of **CSS Modules** that component will be rendered to the following HTML markup in debug (development) mode:

```
<button class="Button_btn_d41d8"><i class="Button_icon_7b91e"></i>Click Me</button>
```

Where each CSS classname is composed of `<ComponentName>-<ClassName>-<Hash>`, effectively avoiding conflicts between CSS classnames with the same names accross multiple components. And in release (production) environment, the same component will be rendered to:

```
<button class="d41d"><i class="7b91"></i>Click Me</button>
```

Where each class name is just a 4-5 characters long hash string.

This is how it works in **[React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)** (disclaimer: I'm the author)

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'right' way to write CSS in React. I'll give you some options and you give them a try and pick what is best for you.

Inline CSS for React:
[Aphrodite](https://github.com/Khan/aphrodite) and [Radium](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium)

Or you can continue using .css files:
Sass, Less, Stylus and PostCSS.

Comment: Is there something negative (for example performance) by using old .css files?

Comment: I like using inline styling to keep everything in one file and also I can use dynamic JS values, but no. There isn't any performance issues using common .css file.

Answer (score 2):

Is a lot subjective, but I suggest you to maintain to use the classic `.css` maybe with some preprocessor. I know that it is fancy follow the promise to have some components entirely portable and that include all its logic and style, but I think that the most clean approach it is to use css for what has been created.

The codebase remain more readable, and you will find always more support and resource for classics workflows.